# On the limits of fractional power sequences.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

This may be a simple question for some but I'm stumped, any suggestions or tips?

$$X_n=(n+3)\sqrt{n+3}-(n+1)\sqrt{n+1}$$

Find $$\lim_{n\to\infty}X_n$$

I've multiplied by the conjugate then expanded the top, to no avail. I'm thinking wee need to use domination principal, and I'm pretty sure it diverges to infinity but if I raise the powers on the bottom, to make a smaller, more simple sequence then use the domination principle to show that $X_n$ diverges to infinity, but the powers then cancel out if I do this.  Any suggestions? My prof is picky.

Comment: Not easy to read. Needs MathJax.

Comment: Use the generalized binomial theorem since $X_n=(n+3)^{3/2}-(n+1)^{3/2}$

Comment: $$X_n = 2\sqrt{n+3} + (n+1)\bigl(\sqrt{n+3} - \sqrt{n+1}\bigr) \geqslant 2 \sqrt{n+3}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left[(n+3) \sqrt{n+3}-(n+1) \sqrt{n+1}\right]$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\left((n+3) \sqrt{n+3}-(n+1) \sqrt{n+1}\right) \left((n+3) \sqrt{n+3}+(n+1) \sqrt{n+1}\right)}{(n+1) \sqrt{n+1}+(n+3) \sqrt{n+3}}$$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n+3)^3-(n+1)^3}{(n+1) \sqrt{n+1}+(n+3) \sqrt{n+3}}$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{6 n^2+24 n+26}{(n+1) \sqrt{n+1}+(n+3) \sqrt{n+3}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2}{n\sqrt n}=+\infty$$

Hope this can be useful

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for, though I may be late.  It doesn't use any outside theorems, and is relevant in university entry level honors calculus, using only basic limit rules.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

With $F(x)=x^{3/2}$, observe that we have $X_n=F(n+3)-F(n+1)$.
Moreover, $F'(x)=\frac32x^{1/2}$ and hence the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus implies that

$$X_n=\int_{n+1}^{n+3}\,\frac32\, x^{1/2}\,dx$$

In particular, $X_n\geq 2\cdot\frac32\, (n+1)^{1/2}=3\,(n+1)^{1/2}\to\infty$ as $n \to\infty$, from which it follows that $X_n$ too diverges to infinity.

---

The same idea can be used to show that $X_n=(n+k_1)^\alpha-(n+k_0)^\alpha$ with $k_1>k_0$ diverges to infinity whenever $\alpha>1$.
The final bound will be

$$(k_1-k_0)\cdot\alpha\cdot{\left(n+k_0\right)}^{\alpha-1}\longrightarrow\infty,$$

as $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=x\sqrt{x}=x^{3/2}$. By Lagrange's theorem

$$ f(n+3)-f(n+1) = 2\,f'(\xi) = 3\sqrt{\xi},\qquad \xi\in [n+1,n+3]$$
so your limit is clearly $+\infty$.